# centering div with css and html

Tags: css

I think I am having a simple problem but I cannot figure it out!

```
<body>
<div id="centerme"/><p>I am a div. I want to be centered.</p>
</body>

#centerme{
margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try closing your div tag and see if that solves your problem.

```
<body>
<div id="centerme"><p>I am a div. I want to be centered.</p> </div>
</body>

#centerme{
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: OK I will do that now.

Comment: It won't let me but I'll do it in 9mins.

Comment: Don't worry Frank. We all have been there. Once I spent like 14 hours trying to solve a problem and here, in stackoverflow, someone gave me the solution with a single css property. That's when I started using this web  both to help and to beign helped

Comment: Take the closing tag of the opener as well. You have <div id="centerme"/> should be <div id="centerme">